# tty frozen/no login on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: login, tty

On Ubuntu 22.04 after upgrade I can no loger login using ctrl alt f5 or similar.

Instead I get a locked up screen showing the boot progress but no prompt for login.

In fact I have the same issue on two pc's.

I can login as a user ok.

Maybe a graphics issue but make no sense as normal desktop works.

Not sure what to check.

Thanks

Comment: Hit `Enter`? Try `Ctrl-Alt-F1`, `Ctrl-Alt-F2`, `Ctrl-Alt-F3`, `Ctrl-Alt-F4`, removing fingers from keyboard in between. The number of virtual consoles is configurable, read `man console`.

Comment: That is not what I mean.  I have been using Ubuntu for more than 10 years.  It is frozen on the tty with no login prompt after you do cntl-alt-f3 or whatever.